# Wireless disable after sleep or shut down

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I have Lenovo Z500 with Windows 10, freshly installed. When computer goes into sleep (or shutdown), Wi-Fi does not work after start.

Interestingly, Wi-fi seems to be enabled (as shown in pic below). I am pretty sure this is driver issue, so I tried many things but did not work:

1- Reset windows 10 (formatting drive)

2- Untick all in Wireless Properties->Power Management

3- Stop windows to update Wi-Fi driver.

4- Use Lenovo N 2230 Driver

5- Use native driver

6- Disable fast boot

I have tried several other drivers as well.

What only works is, restart device again, go to wifi setting, under troubleshoot there is  "Apply this fix". That solves my problem and wifi starts again. This "fix" does not show unless I restart again. (Picture below) What does this fix do programmatically, so that I can do at every restart?

There is no hardware wifi switch in my computer.

What to do now?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAcG2.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAcG2.png)

Comment: Hi, do you know Super User has a built-in image uploading service? Please use that so that your question looks more straightforward with no information hidden behind links.

Comment: Check the bios settings for WLAN or power saving and look thru all the bios options that may be pertinent and available. Consider looking for a [BIOS Update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/IDEAPAD-Z-SERIES-LAPTOPS/IDEAPAD-Z500-NOTEBOOK/downloads/DS035727) that may be newer than the firmware you are running on this machine now. These are some quick ideas.

Comment: imgur is banned in my country, that's why I did not use. I edited anyway. BIOS is up-to-date. What kind of BIOS settings? I checked it all any could not find anything related WIFI